# How do you make a device that can pick up nerve signals?

Tags: arduino, control, robotic-arm, servomotor

I am trying to make a robotic arm that mimics the movement of the user's arm, They way I need it to work is to detect nerve signals and send them to an arduino. The arduino would then have a servo motor mimic the movement of the user's arm when the arduino tells it how quickly to rotate and to what point to rotate, based on the user's input.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Kenneth Carrington, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1):

There are much better solutions to the project which you are trying to accomplish. First off, what I think you are really asking is how to detect muscle movement - not nerve signals.

You could do this by following the 1st solution shown below, but as you will see this method provides limited feedback and is expensive.

**1st way:** Use Myoware - Myoware is a myoelectric sensor that if placed correctly on the desired muscle will sense its movement. This can be used to signal an actuator from the Arduino. To open and close the fingers the sensor would be placed over the flexor digitorum profundus, to move the elbow joint the sensor would be placed over the triceps, and finally, to move the shoulder joint the sensor could be placed on the pectoralis muscle.**Note that this method is very inefficient and expensive - I am also unsure of how to detect the motion of the users wrist through this**

**2nd way** Use Accelerometers/gyroscopes - By placing accelerometers and gyroscopes over each section of the user's arm (which are only a couple of bucks each) you can detect the position, speed, acceleration, etc. of the user's motion along multiple different points. This cannot be done through detecting muscle signals.

**3rd way** Use force/IR sensors - This method is not as good as the 2nd solution presented however is certainly better than the first. By placing a force sensor or a very precise IR sensor over the flexor digitorium profundus, the triceps, and the pectoralis, you can detect the movement of the muscle from the skins surface (eg: when the muscle contracts, more force will be applied to the pressure sensor or the distance from the IR sensor will shrink.

**4th way** Use flexor sensors - Flexor sensors are basically bendy potentiometers. By placing flexor sensors over the user's joints and on each individual finger, you will be able to gain sensory feedback of the position of each joint. The benefit to this is that it allows for more position control (you can control each finger individually), and combined with an accelerometer could also offer information on the speed and acceleration of the movement of each joint.

I have used all 4 methods before in similar projects to yours. In my experience, all though seemingly easier, by trying to use feedback from the user's muscles, you sacrifice a lot of control. These muscle detecting sensors are also quite pricey.

**RECOMMENDED SETUP**
I highly recommend that you use a gyroscope and accelerometer on the elbow, shoulder, and wrist joints to detect their movement and speed. A potentiometer on each of the user's fingers along with an accelerometer will also allow you to control the position and speed of each finger of the robotic hand.

Comment: what if I wanted the user to wear the robotic arm?

Comment: If this is a prosthesis then you would have to go with the force sensor method.

Comment: know anywhere I can buy these parts?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.adafruit.com/force-sensitive-resistor-fsr/using-an-fsr) is a tutorial on the force sensor, and [here](https://www.amazon.com/SENSING-RESISTOR-CIRCLE-1oz-22LB-FLEXIBLE/dp/B00B887CLS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1490655969&sr=8-1&keywords=arduino+force+sensor) is the link to buy one.